# SQLAlchemy - Bulk update using sqlalchemy core table.update() expects all columns in the values data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.4, bulkupdate

I'm trying to do a bulk update using core SQLAlchemy to a postgres database. bulk_update_mappings does not work (reports StaleDataError). So I'm trying to use core functions to do a bulk update. This works fine when the update data passed to the values have all the columns in the db but fails to work when we update only a certain columns. In my application, during periodic syncs between the server and the client only a few of the columns will get updated most of the times.

The code snippet I have for update is :

```
    conn = session.connection()
    table = table_dict[table_key].__table__
    stmt=table.update().where(and_(table.c.user_id==bindparam('uid'),
    tbl_pk[table_key]==bindparam('pkey'))).values()
    conn.execute(stmt, update_list)
```

Since I update multiple tables on every sync, table names and primary keys  are indexed through an array. For the example below table_dict[table_key] would translate to the table 'nwork' and tbl_pk[table_key] would translate to 'table.c.nwid' which would be 'nwork.nwid'.

The update_list is a list of records (that need to get updated) as a python dictionary. When the record has values for all the columns it works fine and when only some of the column is getting updated it's throwing the following error:

```
    StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'last_sync', in parameter group 1 
    [SQL: u'UPDATE nwork SET type=%(type)s, name=%(name)s, last_sync=%(last_sync)s, 
    update_time=%(update_time)s, status=%(status)s, total_contacts=%(total_contacts)s, 
    import_type=%(import_type)s, cur_index=%(cur_index)s WHERE 
    nwork.user_id = %(uid)s AND nwork.nwid = %(pkey)s']
```

In this case the error was happening for a record where last_sync was not getting updated.

What's the way of doing a bulk update where the records may not have all the columns (the same set of them) getting updated? I could not find much information from the Update.values() documentation of SQLAlchemy.

I'm running SQLAlchemy 1.0.14.

Comment: Are the missing columns  nullable?

Comment: Yes they are, but they could have valid non null data in the DB, as part of an earlier update.